# Try to check if Tree is Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

First i insert the tree into an array according to Level order (aka Breadth first) traversal.
and now i check the array

```
 For i=1 to Len(Array) do:
         IF 2*i smaller than Len(Array) then:
            IF Array[i] smaller than Array[2i] OR Array[i] larger than  Array[2i+1] then:
                 Return false
         Else if 2*I larger than Len(Array) then 
            Return True
```

But my problem is the algorithm work only if the tree is a complete binary tree

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, a binary tree is a binary search tree if and only if an inorder traversal of the tree lists the keys in sorted order. Try switching from a level-by-level traversal to an inorder traversal and making appropriate modifications.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ,sorry but i fix it-i have maximum Heap and not BST and i need to check if this is really maximum heap i try to do it with help of array you have another idea?

Comment: You radically edited the question after I posted this answer by changing the question from one about BSTs to one about max-heaps. If you want to ask this question about heaps, I'd recommend posting that as a separate question. If you completely change the question after getting answers, then people won't be very willing to help you.

Comment: sorry i new here,i write new question,thank you from the information

Answer (score 0):

**Clear, concise and efficient code**: Recursion is cool if you actually understand the phenomenon. The idea is to validate each node of the tree as such that it is always between the min and max value. Start with **Integer.MIN_VALUE** and **Integer.MAX_VALUE** as the initial input for min and max.

```
public boolean isBinarySearch(Node root, int min, int max) {

    if (root == null)
        return true;

    return ((min <= root.val && root.val <= max) && (isBinarySearch(
            root.left, min, root.val) && isBinarySearch(root.right,
            root.val, max)));
}
```

You can try this out also.

```
class Node {

public Node left;
public Node right;
public int val;

public Node(int val) {
    this.val = val;
 }
}
```

Now do this.

```
    Node root2 = new Node(12);
    root2.left = new Node(7);
    root2.left.left = new Node(4);
    root2.left.right = new Node(11);
    root2.right = new Node(16);
    root2.right.left = new Node(14);
    root2.right.right = new Node(18);
    root2.right.right.left = new Node(17);

    System.out
            .println("IsBinary="
                    + wc.isBinarySearch(root2, Integer.MIN_VALUE,
                            Integer.MAX_VALUE));
}
```

Comment: Sadly, there is no explicit question. While you answer the title, the implied question may rather have been *What is the minimum change to make my approach work for non-complete binary trees?* - difficult to tell with a user that didn't show up during at least three years.